# Websocket failing connection with phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework

```
App.js:7 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket?token=undefined&vsn=2.0.0' failed:
```

And then in the logs

```
  Transport: :websocket
  Serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer
  Parameters: %{"token" => "SFMyNTY.g2gDYQFuBgBoR0bYggFiAAFRgA._1bc8_ag00XMoZ1WXaqBcIvnaq5muBMW2AUSQ7Avoy0", "vsn" => "2.0.0"}
[info] REFUSED CONNECTION TO RotbWeb.UserSocket in 30µs
  Transport: :websocket
  Serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer
  Parameters: %{"token" => "undefined", "vsn" => "2.0.0"}
[info] REFUSED CONNECTION TO RotbWeb.UserSocket in 35µs
  Transport: :websocket
  Serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer
  Parameters: %{"token" => "undefined", "vsn" => "2.0.0"}
[info] REFUSED CONNECTION TO RotbWeb.UserSocket in 104µs
```

These errors used to be intermittent and I just wait and it resolves itself but it appears it is no longer resolving itself.

Comment: We've experienced the same issue with websockets in Phoenix.  It went from very infrequent (0-10 per day) to 300+ every hour.  From our log archives, I determined the shift happened on June 24, 2022 at 1pm.  We had not deployed any code changes to either our frontend or backend.  One of the most mysterious bugs I've ever encountered.  @bezzoon did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

When Socket connect is refused, you aways want to check the connect callback.

```
def connect(params, socket, info) do
  
  # You are doing something here that makes the connect fail.

end
```

My guess is the token that is `undefined`, you are likely validating the token or some condition that fails and results in the connect failure.